# Eclipse Photon - Unable to clone - Transport Exception - not authorized

Tags: eclipse, github

I created a private repo in github and tried to clone it using Eclipse Photon R.
Import -> Git -> Project from GIT. Then I provided the user and password in the Authentication section and checked the Store in secure storage icon. The authentication pop up keep on coming and after trying the same for 2, 3 times I am getting TransportException: not authorized. I am using the same username and password I used to login to github. In the Preferences-> Secure storage I can see GIT, but no value is associated with it. I tried clearing it and restarting eclipse. Still facing the same issue. Any idea about this ?

Comment: Why Eclipse Photon and not one of the later Eclipse (2021.09) ? There are probably some improvement in Git implementation, especially with authentication... Beside, you could probably clone the repo outside Eclipse (using git bash, tortoise git, ...) and import project in Eclipse.

Comment: Like it says in their doc at https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls, with GitHub and https URLs, you use a personal access token, not your actual password.

Comment: Github no longer support passwords, you must use personal access tokens  - see the duplicate. Note that Photon is now 3 years and 13 releases old.